# Z-Value of clip-space position is always 1.0

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, depth, projection-matrix

I render a lot of quads on the screen into z direction (20 x 2000). I want to get the depth value in a final render target. But it looks like z is always 1.0f. I checked the result with the OpenGL debugger. Any advice?

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 410

layout(row_major) uniform UView
{
    mat4 m_View;
    mat4 m_Projection;
};

layout(row_major) uniform UModelMatrix
{
    mat4 m_ModelMatrix;
};

layout(location=0) in vec2 VertexPosition;

out vec3 PSVSPosition;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 VSPosition = m_View * m_ModelMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition.xy, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    PSVSPosition = VSPosition.xyz;

    gl_Position = m_Projection * VSPosition;
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 410

layout(row_major) uniform USettings
{
   mat4  m_ProjectionMatrix;
};

layout(location = 0) out vec4 PSColor;

in vec3 PSVSPosition;

void main(void)
{       
    // Calculate depth
    vec4 CSPosition = m_ProjectionMatrix * vec4(PSVSPosition, 1.0f);

    CSPosition.xyz /= CSPosition.w;

    PSColor = vec4(vec3(CSPosition.z * 0.5f + 0.5f), 1.0f);
}
```

Result:
[image: Result of render target.]

Closer result:
[image: A little bit of depth if i'm very close to my quad.]

view-space position result:
[image: view-space position result]

clip-space position result:
[image: clip-space position result]

Comment: for me it's looks correct depth for me, as for see it properly you need do some math

Comment: @alexsey-shestacov: But I have rendered the quads from 0 to 2000 "steps" away from the camera. I thought I can see a some shades of grey.

Comment: That's just the way the depth buffer looks; for depth testing it will suffice. If you want more detail out of it then you need to [_linearise_ your depth buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer).

Answer (score 2):

When you divide by the post-projection-matrix .w, you don't get a linear depth from -1 to 1, it mostly gets bunched up near 1.0.

To get linear depth you could do, instead, something akin to:

```
float linearDepth = PSVSPosition.z / 2000.0; // if +2000 is your far plane
PSColor = vec4(vec3(linearDepth), 1.0f);
```

Comment: My near plane is 0.01 and my far plane 4096.0. If I divide with this value I get a dark (everything is black) result. Strange... I have to check the math.

Comment: You may need to divide by -4096, depending how your matrix is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a color ramp to represent the final depth values. Instead of writing the `z` value directly to the pixel, use that value to sample a 1 dimensional texture. This works well because, as you've done, it's easy to get the `z` value into the range of `[0, 1]`. Then you can write the retreived color to the pixel.

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 410

uniform sampler2D UColorRamp;

layout(row_major) uniform USettings
{
   mat4  m_ProjectionMatrix;
};

layout(location = 0) out vec4 PSColor;

in vec3 PSVSPosition;

void main(void)
{       
    // Calculate depth
    vec4 CSPosition = m_ProjectionMatrix * vec4(PSVSPosition, 1.0f);

    CSPosition.xyz /= CSPosition.w;

    vec3 color = texture(UColorRamp, vec2(CSPosition.z * 0.5f + 0.5f, 0.5f)).rgb;

    PSColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);
}
```

Here is a color ramp I've used in the past. It doesn't need to be this tall of course. A height of 1 is sufficient.

[image]